# Importing Excel File in Jupyter lab using Pandas. Getting error "invalid literal for int() with base10: '1e6' "

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to import a sheet in an excel file I have. the exact command is:

```
DATA = pd.read_excel("Excel_data.xlsx",sheet_name = "Sheet1")
```

When I execute this command I get a Value error. The exact output is:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 1e6
```

The sheet is pretty big. It has 1048573 observations and 32 variables

The sheet contains the following data types: 
int64, object, float64

Anyone seen this error before? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try `dtype='object'`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. I still seem to be having problems. I agree this has to be something to do with data types. I will keep fiddling around

Comment: I looked into this further and it may be that during the import process pandas is taking numeric fields (lake a sales value or part qty) and is having problems interpreting any comma's or "." values in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert everything to csv that could help.  Sometimes I have trouble when using .xlsx with pandas but read_csv and .csv work just fine most the time.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to do this in jupyter and not externally (as in saving the file as a ".csv"?) The file is pretty large so it wont open in excel. I have converted the file to csv in R...I just wanted to see if I could do this using pandas

Comment: Save as a csv in excel.  Then do: ```DATA =  pd.read_csv("Excel_data.csv")``` in python.  Make sense?  Please give a point up on my answer if this works for you. :)

Comment: One challenge is that the Excel file is too large to open. I have been able to convert to csv by importing the file in R and then writing it back out as a csv in python. I just thought there would be a way to do this all in pandas